# Form Layout in a Panel using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to layout a form in a panel and have a lot of trouble with the formatting.

I don't seem to be able to put a line break between the Save button and the E-mail label. I have tried moving it down using `<p>` tags. I have tried using form-inline and form-horizontal but only makes things worse.

Alternatively I would like to place the Save button directly next to the textbox but again can't seem to achieve this.

A jsfiddle for an example https://jsfiddle.net/omyuzuu3/.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="leftCol">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <strong>Account Details</strong><p>
            <hr>
            <form class="form"  method="post" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2">Username</label><p>
                <input name="txtUsername" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php  echo $user->loadUser()->username; ?>">           
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="btnSaveUsername" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Save</button>
                <p>
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <p>
                <label for="exampleInputName2">E-mail</label><p>
                <input name="txtEmail"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php  echo $user->loadUser()->email; ?>">

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" name="btnSaveEmail" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Save</button>
              </div>

              </form>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `float:right` on the save button.

Float element is out of the normal flow, so its container's height does not account for the floating element

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvt73.png

Add the clearfix property to floating element's container would fix the issue

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUhTp.png

Bootstrap already contains `.clearfix` class for adding clearfix css properties

[What is clearfix ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)